# jQuery's Button Function Stopped Working with Bootstrap 5

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5

I have been incorporating Bootstrap into my jQuery project. The following code used to apply jQuery UI's theme to all buttons but now it doesn't.

```
$("button").button();
```

This seems to only happen to buttons added dynamically through AJAX calls. The buttons are styled fine on initial page load.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Could be any number of reasons for this, add more information to the question. Are there javascript errors in the console? Are you running that piece of code before the page is ready?

Answer (score 1):

Either import [jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/button/) into your project or use `$("button").addClass('ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all');` instead of `$("button").button();`